# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED When i Need to Upload Picture in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I use Angular for the client-side and use ASP.NET Core in the backend.

I need to upload a picture in ASP.NET Core and I use this code:

```
 private readonly IApplicationRootSiteData _applicationRoot;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hostingEnvironment"></param>
    /// <param name="applicationRoot"></param>
    public UploadController(
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        IApplicationRootSiteData applicationRoot)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _applicationRoot = applicationRoot;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Upload Picture
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost("UploadNewsPic"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public IActionResult UploadNewsPic()
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, _applicationRoot.ProductMainPictureFolder)))
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, _applicationRoot.RootPath)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, _applicationRoot.RootPath));
                }
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, _applicationRoot.UploadProductPicturePath())))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, _applicationRoot.UploadProductPicturePath()));
                }
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, _applicationRoot.UploadProductMainPicturePath())))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, _applicationRoot.UploadProductMainPicturePath()));
                }
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(_applicationRoot.UploadNewPath(), file.Name);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is startuup class :

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler();
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.AddSwaggerUI();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

but when I send the request to ASP.NET Core, I get this error:

> OPTIONS https://localhost:44390//api/v1/Upload/UploadNewsPic
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What's the problem? How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one in startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
      PerformCorsSetup(services);
 } 

 private static void PerformCorsSetup(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ********************
        // Setup CORS
        // ********************
        var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin(); // For anyone access.
                                      //corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:56573"); // for a specific url. Don't add a forward slash on the end!
        corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {

            options.AddPolicy("SiteCorsPolicy", corsBuilder.Build());
        });
    }
```

and this on in controller:

```
[EnableCors("SiteCorsPolicy")]
   public UploadController()
{
  ///etc
}
```